# java.text.Normalizer equivalent for Java ME (to replace accented characters)

Tags: java, string, java-me, midp

I would like to know if there exists a class or library for Java ME that emulates what java.text.Normalizer does.

I want to be able to replace accented characters with non-accented versions of the same characters (in Portuguese). Eg: "coração" ===> "coracao".

Using `Normalizer` class, it would be:

```
Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
```

I want to be able to replace accented characters in the most efficient manner possible in Java ME.

Comment: does your target device support [JSR 238 mobile i18n](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=238)?

Comment: I am not designing for a particular device. I want to support any CLDC-1.1/MIDP-2 devices. So, some may not support JSR 238.

Answer (score 0):

[icu4j](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/) is IBM's effort on internationalisation. The package *com.ibm.icu.text* seems to be where your functionality can be found. For Java ME you would probably need to prune the library, as it is large (because of its full unicode and all languages nature). You might use a code obfuscator for that.